# LuaTeX for memoir and microtype

Tags: xetex, luatex, memoir

I'm typesetting a novel using the `memoir` class and trying to figure out whether to use XeTeX or LuaTeX. As per the [microtype documentation](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf), `protrusion`, `expansion` and `(=auto)` work with LuaTeX, but only `protrusion` works with XeTeX.

Does this matter much when it comes to a novel?

Comment: Probably not ... unless, perhaps, it is self-published ... or perhaps even: self-published and you want to publish, say, an [ergodic novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_literature) like [*House of Leaves*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Leaves#Format). If you hope to get someone else to publish it, you might want to focus on keeping it as easy as possible to convert it to other formats in case publishers don't want your PDF.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. For sure, issues of page size and page layout, margin choices, font type choices, and font size choices are far more important than any microtype-related choices.

Comment: @jon yes, I'm planning to publish it myself, and it is just plain text. No pictures, nothing. I'm concerned about the justification, inter-word spacing and hyphenation. How would all this work with XeTeX?

Comment: @mico I chose XeTeX coz I'll have more flexibility with fonts. :)

Comment: Well, `microtype` helps with justification matters generally.  (I prefer LuaTeX as a matter of choice; and pdfTeX when I'm doing something simple and quick.  But I don't write novels.)  Note that XeTeX does not give more flexibility with fonts (compared to LuaTeX).

Comment: OK, but otherwise LuaTeX does pretty much everything that XeTeX does, and both have the same level of flexibility (if not more) for custom fonts?

Comment: Yes. As a general rule, LuaTeX probably has at least more potential functionality because you can exploit the power of Lua, too. But both use the same `fontspec` package for LaTeX (i.e., if you use `lualatex` or `xelatex` to compile rather than 'plain' `xetex` or `luatex`). As an end-user, the only difference you're likely to notice is that documents compiled with `lualatex` take longer than those with `xelatex`.

Comment: Wonderful. I'll use LuaLaTeX in that case. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`microtype` has defaults which can take care of most of the text in `memoir`. I tried the defaults with LuaLaTeX as well as XeLaTeX. And then I tried it with pdfLaTeX. I liked the output of pdfLaTeX as well as LuaLaTeX.

**Takeaway**: LuaLaTeX seems to work better with `microtype`, when compared with XeLaTeX.